# The requested interface implements a protected class

Tags: javascript, nfc, webusb

I want to read NFC card's data the `ACR1252` using reader through the browser. the reader is successfully seen by the browser, but it does not allow me to access the interface to implement authorization by scanning the NFC card
here is my code

```js
async function requestUSB() {
  const filters = [
    { vendorId: 0x072f, productId: 0x223b }
  ];

  try {
    const device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: filters });
    console.log('Device found:', device);

    // Open the device
    await device.open();
    console.log('Device opened:', device)

    // Claim the interface for communication
    await device.claimInterface(1);
    console.log('Interface claimed');
```

and I'm getting this error: **The requested interface implements a protected class.**

I understand that using `WebUSB` it's not possible to get access to blocked interface due security. But there is any other ways to get data from NFC card into the browser using JavaScript? Any API suggestions?

Comment: Just to confirm, is interface 1 Smart card class? (https://wicg.github.io/webusb/#:~:text=Mass%20Storage-,0x0B,Smart%20Card,-0x0E).